# Use async pipe to show Observable data retrieved from the Application State

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, store, application-state

I have code that gets data from the **Application State** and then show data inside component.html.

**component.ts**

```
myData$: Observable<IMyData>;

ngOnInit() {
   this.myData$ = this.myStore.select(fetchMyData);

   // here I get a code and I use it to dispatch a new action
   this.myStore.select(codeSelector).pipe(
      map((code) => this.myStore.dispatch(myDataAction({ code: code })))
    ).subscribe();
}
```

**component.html**

```
{{myData$.myField}}
```

The code above works perfectly.

Now, instead of calling the **subscribe()** method inside **component.ts**, I'd like to use `async` pipe inside **component.html**, this way:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="myData$ | async as data">
{{data.myField}}
```

When I do this nothing is shown inside component.html. I understood that inside my latter code I have problems with the operators I used.

I used the async pipe many times, but only when dispatching standard actions; I never used it when the action was dispatched inside an operator.

Can you helping me understanding my error?

Comment: Inside map operator you are returning action instead of obserable  map((code) => this.myStore.dispatch(myDataAction({ code: code })))

Comment: Hi @Chellappanவ, how should I edit my code?

Comment: Your `subscribe()` is subscribing to `this.myStore.select(codeSelector)`. Without it, your store selector won't return anything since it is a cold observable. And in return, it won't run your action, and possibly won't update your store data that `fetchMyData` is selecting.
Btw, as one answer suggests, you should use `tap()` instead of `map()`

Comment: Hi @FrankFajardo, thank you for the explanation. Now I get that I have to subscribe to "this.myStore.select(codeSelector)" in order to make "this.myData$ = this.myStore.select(fetchMyData)" works; then I can use async pipe on "myData$" inside the template.

Answer (score 1):

Try tap operator for side effects intead of map

```
   data$ = this.myStore.select(codeSelector).pipe(
      tap((code) => this.myStore.dispatch(myDataAction({ code: code })))
    )
```

Then inside component

```
<ng-container *ngIf="myData$ | async as data">
</ng-container>
```

Comment: hi @Chellapan, probably I didn't explain well. If I use subscribe(), as you suggested,  my code works. What I was trying to do is to avoid using .subscribe() and use async pipe  (that automatically subscribe and unsubscribe) inside the template

Comment: acutally when using async pipe you dont need to subscribe inside component inside you can use tap operator. it will get invoked when async pipe resolved

Comment: Thank for you help man. Actually the code you wrote is exactly the code I wrote before looking for help here on stackOverflow. There was just on little difference:  I can't do "data$ = this.myStore.select..." because "data$" has a type (as you can see in my post is "IMyData" type), and "this.myStore.select..." return just a string (that I just pass to the action).  Anyway I think FrankFajardo hit the spot: I have to subscribe() to "this.myStore.select(codeSelector)" to make the whole code working.

Comment: @Matt yes you need to subscribe inorder to get the flow works.